# Error on create a Button Listener

Tags: android, button, listener, actionlistener

My intent is to get text from an EditText and view it in a Toast message. The code is this:

```
package com.example.primaapplicazione;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) 
    {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

public void fromEditToToast()
{
    EditText e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {   
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment 
{
    public PlaceholderFragment() 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }

}

}
```

If I call the method "fromEditToToast()" in onCreate() without the "setOnClickListener()", it compiles properly and the app opens. If I call the same method with that function on the emulator app doesn't open, showing this message "Unfortunately, PrimaApplicazione has stopped.

What should I have to do?

Comment: You should post the LogCat output with all the colorful red lines that will likely occur a little before you see the message " Unfortunately,..." We can only speculate until then. It sounds like their might be an issue with the instantiation of the button. You might also want to post your layout xml as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this is a very common error, The `PlaceholderFragment` uses the `fragment_main.xml` that must contain the elements `editText1` and `button1`, probably you have that elements defined in your `activity_main.xml`

Answer (score 0):

It may be that views are not being instantiated while the activity has started. Device works faster than emulator so it might work in a device while not in emulator.

Implement your onClickListener directly in fragment and show the toast from there, it will work (**assuming EditText and Button lies in fragment**).

Try following code in your fragment and call the following function in your fragment's onViewCreated function to set the button's listener : -

```
private void set buttonOnClickListener()
{
    EditText e = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button b = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);

   b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {   
              //your code goes here;
        }
    });
}
```